# how to focus next textfield when button clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML :

```
<input type="text" class="mytextbox">
<input type="text" class="mytextbox">
<input type="text" class="mytextbox">
<input type="text" class="mytextbox">

<input type="button" class="mybutton" value="focus next" onclick="focusNext()">
<input type="button" class="mybutton" value="focus prev" onclick="focusPrev()">
```

JS code :

```
//focused is getting last focused textfield
var focused = null;
$(".mytextbox").focus(function(){
    focused = $(this);
});

//focus next
function focusNext(){
    $(".mytextbox").each(

        //checking is this textbox focused
        if($(this)[0] == focused[0]){
              $(this).next().focus(); 
              //or
              $(this).next(".mytextbox").focus(); 
        }
    );
}

//focus prev
function focusPrev(){
    $(".mytextbox").each(

        //checking is this textbox focused
        if($(this)[0] == focused[0]){
              $(this).prev().focus(); 
              //or
              $(this).prev(".mytextbox").focus(); 
        }
    );
}
```

i think `$(this).next()` is not working.. is `next()` function not working in each ???

how can i focus next or previous text field when button clicked?
Help me.. and thank you..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your script you have synatx errors as `.each()` should have a function as its param.

Apart from that there is a logical error in the each loop, since you are calling `focus()` in the loop the focus handler will get called and will chage the variable referred by `focus` so the next iteration also will be true so the `Next` button will not work.

```
var focused = null;
$(".mytextbox").focus(function () {
    focused = $(this);
});

//focus next
function focusNext() {
    if (focused && focused.length) {
        focused.next('.mytextbox').focus();
    }
}

//focus prev
function focusPrev() {
    if (focused && focused.length) {
        focused.prev('.mytextbox').focus();
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/stq4xn2d/)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that first input field is focused by default when page loads, please see below code -

HTML : put `id`s for button to bind click event

```
<input type="text" class="mytextbox">
<input type="text" class="mytextbox">
<input type="text" class="mytextbox">
<input type="text" class="mytextbox">

<input id="nextBtn" type="button" class="mybutton" value="focus next">
<input id="prevBtn" type="button" class="mybutton" value="focus prev">
```

jQuery : set focus for first field. Check if next or prev element is present when click on next or previous button and then set focus accordingly.

```
$(function(){
  //focus first input fields
  $(".mytextbox:first").focus();
  var currentFocusedInput = $(".mytextbox:first");

  // next button
  $("#nextBtn").click(function(){
     var nextInputToFocus = currentFocusedInput.next('.mytextbox');
     if($(nextInputToFocus).length > 0)
      {
        currentFocusedInput = $(nextInputToFocus);
      }
      $(currentFocusedInput).focus();
  });

  // previous button
  $("#prevBtn").click(function(){
     var prevInputToFocus = currentFocusedInput.prev('.mytextbox');
     if($(prevInputToFocus).length > 0)
      {
        currentFocusedInput = $(prevInputToFocus);
      }
      $(currentFocusedInput).focus();
  });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/hyqbkfj8/2/)**